# I have a simple video that I want when it's up to 1:00 minute,the video pause

Tags: java, android

I have a simple video that I want when it's up to 1:00 minute,the video pause

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    VideoView v;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        v=findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        String vediopath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.testvedio;
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(vediopath);
        v.setVideoURI(uri);
        v.start();

     
    }
}
```